# SQL Procedure that Insert in a table a result of a dynamic query

Tags: procedure, dynamicquery, sql-server-2014-express

Im trying a lot of combination but always having errors.
(the Select/insert with replacing my variable in hard code is working outside of procedure)

Basically my proc have to do a dynamic select that receives a date variable as string and return a table  as result and should insert it in other existing table.
code removing part of the dynamic query(too big):

```
alter procedure [dbo].[SavePosition]
(@Refdate as varchar(15) =null)
as
begin
set NOCOUNT on
declare @YdDate as varchar(15)
declare @SQL AS NVARCHAR(max)

--To get prior date from @refdate(standalone select working well):
set @YdDate = (SELECT distinct max(TradeDate) from Trades where TradeDate < @Refdate)

--Sample of the query:
set @SQL='Select  ('''+ @Refdate +''') AS Refdate, @('''+ @YdDate +''') as Product from...join..having...group...';

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Position]([Refdate],[Product],...)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
end
go
```

when I run below I receive a lot of: "The multi-part identifier "...." could not be bound."

```
exec [dbo].[SavePosition] '2014-12-10'
```

Comment: still get '"The multi-part identifier "...." could not be bound."'

Answer (score 0):

You need to store complete insert statement in @SQL variable. Please try like this.

set @SQL='INSERT INTO [dbo].Position Select  ('''+ @Refdate +''') AS Refdate, @('''+ @YdDate +''') as Product from...join..having...group...';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

Comment: error: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 436
Incorrect syntax near 'as'." what puzzles me in that my script even have 436 lines :/